# Custom (round) toggle button

Tags: android, button, toggle

I am trying to build a custom toggle button in Android, I want it to look like radio button but function as toggle button. Can some one help me with this? any clue hints close to answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the RadioButton view and RadioGroup layout?

```
RadioButton myRadioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.myradiobutton);
myRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          // Toggle the radio button on click.
          RadioButton button = (RadioButton)v;
          button.setChecked(!button.isChecked());                   
     }
});
```

Comment: will try now and let you know, I cannot group them as Radio Group, I want to have individual readio buttons, that serve the purpose of toggle/check box

Comment: If this has worked in the past it no longer works now on an HTC Hero running 2.1u1.

Answer (score 10):

You need to override the look of the toggle button via some custom xml

quick overview:

- create png files with the look and feel of your buttons, if you like the radio buttons, grab them from ...\eclipse_android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-hdpi
- in your layout xml 

         android:background="@drawable/round_toggle" />
- add selectors with as many states (up to 6 + default) in round_toggle.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/roundtoggle_on_pressed" />
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/roundtoggle_on_focused" />
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false"    
       android:drawable="@drawable/roundtoggle_on_normal" />       
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/roundtoggle_off_pressed" />
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/roundtoggle_off_focused" />
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/roundtoggle_off_normal" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/roundtoggle_off_normal" />
  </selector>
  ```

full details in http://www.anddev.org/act_custom_togglebuttons-t10620.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-skinning a checkbox.  The following link is a tutorial on doing so:

[link](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html)

Comment: Hello Andrew, thank you for reply, but I do not want the tick mark to be displayed. Hence I want a radio button look, if you know how to set radio button to true on click , and then set to false again on click , then please let me know.